# How to restrict a JWT / OpenID token to specific IP / CIDR

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt, openid-connect

I'm developing an [OpenID connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html)/JWT auth provider and part of the module is to allow the client to get a token and use it only with a specific IP address (if the client requests so).
  I was thinking to make use of the scopes (i.e. to basically prefix them with the IP address and use an internal function to encode/decode it like 127.0.0.1:::getEmail) but if there is any standard I would definitely like to use it rather than to butcher the scopes.
  Is there any other field that I can use to store this information? (e.g. `azp`).

Comment: did you figure this out?  I'm using OpenId Connect Server and looking to do the same.  I'm not sure where these as set.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevent you from creating a new claim set in your JWT.
When the JWT is issued by your provider and if the client requested it, one (or more) IP address(es) could be added into your JWT payload.
Then, the resource server will take this claim into account.

Example:

`{
    "exp": 123456789
    "iss": "Provider"
    "aud": "Resource Server"
    "sub": "My Client"
    "ips": ["127.0.0.1","192.168.0.0/24"]
}`